# onActivityResult not getting string out of Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I need some help with my android app. I have two activities, first starts the second one with `startActivityForResult()`. When the second one closes it sends the intent as it should, however when i want to access extra from `onActivityResult()` i get a null instead of what I put in. 
I also tried using bundle with

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
b.getString(AddTable.EXTRA_NAME);
```

but it resulted in RuntimeException and failure delivering result.

Here's my code:

```
public class RunnerApp extends Activity {

    private ListView listView;
    private static ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private Intent newTable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_runner_app);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void addTable(View v){
        newTable = new Intent(this, AddTable.class);
        startActivityForResult(newTable, 1);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null){
        data = getIntent();
        Log.d("add", "got intent");
        String newName = data.getStringExtra(AddTable.EXTRA_NAME);
            Log.d("add", "string " + newName); //always prints string null
            values.add(newName);
            Log.d("add", "added to list");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_runner_app);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Second activity started by `startActivityForResult()`

```
public class AddTable extends Activity {

    public final static String EXTRA_NAME = "com.example.runnerapp.NAME";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_table);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_add_table, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void addThisTable(View v) {
        Intent addTable = new Intent(this, RunnerApp.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addTableField);
        String name = editText.getText().toString();
        addTable.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME, name);
        Log.d("intenyt", name);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, addTable);
        this.finish();
    }

}
```

Comment: If you take out `new Intent(this, RunnerApp.class);` and leave it as just `new Intent()`, does that work?

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first activity your code reads

```
data = getIntent();
```

But the actual data you want is in

```
data.getData()
```

Answer (score 0):

use this in the onActivityResult function..

```
data.getStringExtra(EXTRA_NAME)
```